update size of Scrollable bar in pysimpleGUI
Basically I have the same issue than this one : issue
I tried this before but I get an error message, I think because I am using frames (I think).
As you can see I tried using window.visibility_changed() but it did not help.
Test code to explain :
import PySimpleGUI as sg 

def frame (n_frame):
    layout = [[sg.Text  ('test')]]   
    
    return layout

def make_window():
    layout = [[sg.Column([[sg.Text  ('Title')],          # First title of the IDS 
                          [sg.Column(frame(1),key = '-LVL 1 CALL-')],
                          [sg.pin   (sg.Frame(title  = '',
                                              layout = [[sg.Button(' + ',key = '-ADD A LVL 1 FRAME-'),
                                                         sg.Button(' - ',key = '-REMOVE A LVL 1 FRAME-'),
                                                         sg.Button('Save')]],
                                              relief = 'flat'))]],
                        scrollable=True,  
                        vertical_scroll_only=True,
                        pad =(0,0))]]   
    window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, metadata=1, resizable = True, element_padding = (10, 6), finalize = True)
    return window

def main():
    window = make_window()
    
    while True:
        event, values   = window.read()
        
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event =='Save':
            break
    
        elif event == '-ADD A LVL 1 FRAME-' : 
            window.metadata += 1 
            window.extend_layout(window['-LVL 1 CALL-'],(frame(window.metadata)))
            window.refresh()
            window.visibility_changed()
            window['-LVL 1 CALL-'].contents_changed()

    window.close()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    main()

The error message :
File "C:\...\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 8302, in contents_changed
    self.TKColFrame.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.TKColFrame.canvas.bbox('all'))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Frame' object has no attribute 'canvas'


Additional questions :

I would like to update the size of it without having to call .contents_changed() on the specific window that has just been added because I have just so many
I would like the scrollbar to adapt to the size of the window if the user resize window

These are less important and I can also find by myself, thank you for your help


I would like to update the size of it without having to call .contents_changed() on the specific window that has just been added because I have just so many

Call method contents_changed only for the scrollable Column element, so here you may add a key, like -Column-, to main scrollable Column element.
def make_window():
    layout = [[sg.Column([[sg.Text  ('Title')],          # First title of the IDS
                          [sg.Column(frame(1),key = '-LVL 1 CALL-')],
                          [sg.pin   (sg.Frame(title  = '',
                                              layout = [[sg.Button(' + ',key = '-ADD A LVL 1 FRAME-'),
                                                         sg.Button(' - ',key = '-REMOVE A LVL 1 FRAME-'),
                                                         sg.Button('Save')]],
                                              relief = 'flat'))]],
                        scrollable=True,
                        vertical_scroll_only=True,
                        pad =(0,0),
                        key="-Column-",                 # Add key here
                        )]]
    window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, metadata=1, resizable = True, element_padding = (10, 6), finalize = True)
    return window

then you can call method contents_changed of the '-Column-' Column element, like
        elif event == '-ADD A LVL 1 FRAME-' :
            window.metadata += 1
            window.extend_layout(window['-LVL 1 CALL-'],(frame(window.metadata)))
            window.refresh()
            window.visibility_changed()
            window['-Column-'].contents_changed()


I would like the scrollbar to adapt to the size of the window if the user resize window

It is much complex to make the scrollable Column to expand when it or window configured, following code demo the way about how I do it, and it need more knowledge about the tkinter.
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def repack(widget, option):
    pack_info = widget.pack_info()
    pack_info.update(option)
    widget.pack(**pack_info)

def configure_canvas(event, canvas, frame_id):
    canvas.itemconfig(frame_id, width=canvas.winfo_width())

def configure_frame(event, canvas):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def cell(i):
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Hello World', expand_x=True, key=f'TA{i}'),
         sg.Text('Hello World', expand_x=True, justification='center', key=f'TB{i}')]
    ]
    return [[sg.Frame(f'Frame {i}', layout, background_color='blue', expand_x=True, key=f'FRAME{i}')]]


layout = [
    [sg.Button('New Frame')],
    [sg.Column(cell(0), scrollable=True,  vertical_scroll_only=True, pad=(0, 0), expand_x=True, expand_y=True, key='COLUMN')],
]
location = sg.Window.get_screen_size()
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, resizable=True, finalize=True, margins=(0, 0), location=location)

repack(window[f'TA{0}'].widget, {'fill':'none', 'expand':0, 'before':window[f'TB{0}'].widget})

column = window['COLUMN'].widget
frame_id, frame, canvas = column.frame_id, column.TKFrame, column.canvas

canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas, frame_id=frame_id:configure_canvas(event, canvas, frame_id))
frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas:configure_frame(event, canvas))

window.set_size((320, 240))
window.refresh()
window.move_to_center()

count = 1

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'New Frame':
        window.extend_layout(window['COLUMN'], cell(count))
        repack(window[f'TA{count}'].widget, {'fill':'none', 'expand':0, 'before':window[f'TB{count}'].widget})
        count += 1

window.close()


Thank you for this, Then you would recommend to set up an initial size and then make it scrollable ?

The size (320, 240) set for full view of the layout initially, of course, you can use option size_subsample_height=1 and default size_subsample_width=1 in a scrollable sg.Column element for it.
